# Unix commands work on server but not in ruby ssh session

Tags: ruby

I am trying to learn how to use the net-ssh gem for ruby. I want to execute the commands below, after I login to the directory - /home/james.

```
cd /
pwd
ls
```

When I do this with putty, it works and i can see a list of directories. But, when I do it with ruby code, it does not give me the the same output.

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'net/ssh'

host = 'server'
user = 'james'
pass = 'password123'

def get_ssh(host, user, pass)
    ssh = nil
    begin
        ssh = Net::SSH.start(host, user, :password => pass)
        puts "conn successful!"
    rescue
        puts "error - cannot connect to host"
    end
    return ssh
end

conn = get_ssh(host, user, pass)

def exec(linux_code, conn)
    puts linux_code
    result = conn.exec!(linux_code)
    puts result
end

exec('cd /', conn)
exec('pwd', conn)
exec('ls', conn)

conn.close
```

Output -

```
conn successful!
cd /
nil
pwd
/home/james
ls
nil
```

I was expecting pwd to give me / instead of /home/james. That is how it works in putty. What is the mistake in the ruby code?

Comment: You may want to look at [mina](http://mina-deploy.github.io/mina/command_queue.html) which allows you to queue up commands which are run in a single ssh session.

Comment: @MarkThomas - Thanks. But, I am desperately hoping to make it happen with ruby net-ssh. I wonder which part of the documentation would tell me if its even possible to do that or not.

Comment: That is not ruby problem, that is just expected behavior of putty and ruby-ssh consequently. So putty enters by default to the root folder, and ruby-ssh as well as the usual Linux ssh enters to home folder

Comment: But try the complex command at once and give the output - cd / ; pwd

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i execute 2 or more commands in the same ssh session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671392/how-can-i-execute-2-or-more-commands-in-the-same-ssh-session)

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29149513/520567

Answer (score 3):

It seems like every command runs on it's own environment, so the current directory is not carried over exec to exec. You can verify this if you do:

`exec('cd / && pwd', conn)`

It will print `/`. It is not clear from the documentation how to make all the commands execute on the same environment or if this is even possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `net/ssh` is stateless, so it opens a new connection with each command execution.
You can use the [rye](https://github.com/delano/rye) gem that implements a work around for this. but I do not know if it works with ruby > 2, since its development is not that active.

Another way is to use a [pty](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) process, in which you'll open a pseudo terminal with the `ssh` command, than use the input and output files to write commands for the terminal and read the results. To read the results you need to use the [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-select) method of the IO class. But you need to learn how to use those utilities since its not that obvious for a non experienced programmer.

Comment: Thanks. But, I am desperately hoping to make it happen with ruby net-ssh. I wonder which part of the documentation would tell me if its even possible to do that or not.

Comment: I tried this when I was building a RaspberryPi (linux machines) clients manager, using sinatra, angularJS and net-ssh. At that time I needed to be able to open a web terminal to selected client an run commands like on a linux terminal. I tried to make it with net-ssh, but I did not arrive to any good solution, so I made it using `pty` and it was the best solution I was able to implement.

Comment: Look at my second answer, It gives an example on how to do what you want just by using `net-ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

And, Yey, I found how to do that, and in fact it is so simple. I think I did not get to this solution last time, because I was a little new to this thing of net-ssh, pty terminal. But yey, I found it finally, and here and example.

```
require 'net/ssh'

shell = {} #this will save the open channel so that we can use it accross threads
threads = []
# the shell thread
threads << Thread.new do
  # Connect to the server
  Net::SSH.start('localhost', 'your_user_name', password: 'your_password') do |session|
    # Open an ssh channel
    session.open_channel do |channel|   
      # send a shell request, this will open an interactive shell to the server 
      channel.send_channel_request "shell" do |ch, success|    
        if success      
          # Save the channel to be used in the other thread to send commands
          shell[:ch] = ch
          # Register a data event
          # this will be triggered whenever there is data(output) from the server
          ch.on_data do |ch, data|
              puts data
          end  
        end  
      end  
    end  
  end  
end

# the commands thread
threads << Thread.new do
  loop do
    # This will prompt for a command in the terminal
    print ">"
    cmd = gets
    # Here you've to make sure that cmd ends with '\n'
    # since in this example the cmd is got from the user it ends with 
    #a trailing eol
    shell[:ch].send_data cmd
    # exit if the user enters the exit command
    break if cmd == "exit\n"
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

and here we are, an interactive terminal using net-ssh ruby gem.
For more info look [here](http://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v1/chapter-5.html) its for the previous version 1, but it is so useful for you to understand how every piece works. And [here](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Channel.html#method-i-send_channel_request)